# How to add a user to django-tagging

Tags: django, tagging, django-tagging

I'm looking for a way to add "user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)" to django-tagging model with templatetags support but my django knowledge is too low to understand the code of django-tagging.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the tagging register function

```
import tagging

class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

tagging.register(UserModel)
```

Take a look http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt